# sum accounting session on mysql avoiding duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an account table like this:

> **acct:(id, acctuniqueid, name,sessiontime)**

I would like to calculate total time used by the name=XXXXXX, but avoiding acctuniqueid duplicates. I'm trying the following query, but I get syntax error in the result:

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(sessiontime),0) 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM acct WHERE name='XXXXX' GROUP BY `acctuniqueid`)
;
```

Any suggestion??

Thank you in advance

Comment: WHats the error?    sum(ifnull(sessiontime,0) is probably a better way of writing that, you want to handle the nulls before summing, not after.

Comment: I think you are missing alias for the derived table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'r missing table alias for derived table, like:

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(sessiontime),0) as total_time
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM acct WHERE name='XXXXX' GROUP BY `acctuniqueid`) as temp
;
```

Comment: Generally speaking:SELECT alias.col1, alias.col2
FROM tablename alias;
SELECT alias.col1, alias.col2
FROM (
  ... subquery goes here
) alias

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
SELECT acctuniqueid
,coalesce(SUM(sessiontime),0) Total 
FROM acct 
WHERE name='XXXXX' 
GROUP BY `acctuniqueid`;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31467/1